# Adding Post With Featured Image Programmatically

Tags: php, wordpress

I am adding posts dynamically to wordpress. I am using following code to create post and add a featured image which is working fine but there are 2 problems

1. It adds 2 posts 1 with image itself no other content and correct with post with that image as featured image .
2. Featured image in post size large .

   $post_id = wp_insert_post( $postdata, true );
            //Saving  Image from a url
            $attachmentId_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment,$fullpathfilename,0);
           add_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachmentId, true );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wp_insert_attachment creates a post itself if parent id is set to zero.

try:

```
wp_insert_attachment( $attachment,$fullpathfilename,$post_id);
```